# Running two browsers with separate network interfaces

Tags: wifi, applications, networking, firefox, ethernet

I need to connect to the internet via wifi connection with firefox while maintaining ethernet connection to another router via second separate firefox setup installed with snap. How do i do such a juggling?

Comment: Isn't this something that routing can help you with? You will have a default route (usually ethernet given the choice of ethernet + wifi) but if you want to visit one site via wifi and another via ethernet, you can force the traffic to the first site by setting a route via your wifi for that address. Check out in the terminal `man ip` for help or simply run `ip route show` to see what you have now.

Comment: Alternatively, you can bind different apps to different networks. So alongside Firefox, install Brave or something else and then read up this example on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/241178/how-to-use-different-network-interfaces-for-different-processes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this within Firefox. If you do a 'firefox --help' on the command line there is no switch to specify a specific network interface.

You could work around that by creating a local proxy for one of the interfaces and use a custom profile for that one instance of Firefox and point it at the your new local proxy inside the profile.

Something like:

$ firefox --profile  --new-instance

or something along those lines - you'll have to play with it to make it work.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Personally, i have achieved something like that. I used my laptop to pick up the wifi. Then, used the ethernet on the laptop to run to my xp desktop. the trick to it is one of the wifi connections has to be shared if i can remember right its the ethernet port. This can all be done by 
-clicking the wifi symbol
-networks settings
-then at the bottom there's a tab edit connections then
-under ipv4 tab,set the ipv4 to shared with other computers
-under ipv6 tab, set the ipv6 to disabled
-make sure your link negotiation is on automatic
- top two boxes under the general tab are checked 
- and it may not be wise but i also had all the boxes under the tab dcb unchecked Then again i may be wrong. It may take some tinkering. also, if you are talking about using one computer and two connections separately, i would think a vm would be the only way to seperate the two incoming connections in to different browsers.